# How to pass list of custom functions to pandas.Dataframe.aggregate

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, lambda, scipy

I am trying to aggregate a `pd.Dataframe` with different custom functions, particularly from `scipy.stats`. I can get it to work with a single function, in this case `trim_mean`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import trim_mean

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 3), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'], index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=100))

# this works as expected
df.agg([np.sum, np.mean])

# now with a different function, works also
df.agg(lambda x: trim_mean(x, 0.2))

# apply also works
df.apply(lambda x: trim_mean(x, 0.2))
```

However, `df.agg([lambda x: trim_mean(x, 0.2)])` generates an `IndexError: tuple index out of range'` as does `df.apply([lambda x: trim_mean(x, 0.2)])`.

I found an [old issue on pandas-dev](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/7186) but that doesn't make sense to me.

Help, anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `lambda` before list of functions, for return `DataFrame` use `Series`:

```
c = ['trim_mean','mean','sum']
print (df.agg(lambda x: pd.Series([trim_mean(x, 0.2), np.mean(x), np.sum(x)], index=c)))
```

Or:

```
print (df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series([trim_mean(x, 0.2), np.mean(x), np.sum(x)], index=c)))
```

---

```
                   A         B         C
trim_mean  -0.143219 -0.018430 -0.097768
mean       -0.171887 -0.042308 -0.004843
sum       -17.188738 -4.230797 -0.484343
```

Verify:

```
print (df.agg([np.sum, np.mean]))
              A         B         C
sum  -17.188738 -4.230797 -0.484343
mean  -0.171887 -0.042308 -0.004843

print(df.agg(lambda x: trim_mean(x, 0.2)))
A   -0.143219
B   -0.018430
C   -0.097768
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

You are giving a list as an argument and they both expect some function, so use:

```
df.agg(*[lambda x: trim_mean(x, 0.2)])
```

Or:

```
df.apply(*[lambda x: trim_mean(x, 0.2)])
```

To unpack those functions from list as arguments.

However, if you have multiple `lambda`s you'll encounter the error you googled because they hold the same name.